# Curves whose normals are perpendicular to each other

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

One day in math class, we were working on homework. It involved calculus, and looking at $e^x$ and $e^x/2$. From a small section of the graph, it looked like if you chose any point on $e^x$, the normal (the perpendicular of the tangent) would be perpendicular to $e^x/2$ as well. For any point.
Which was completely stupid I found out later, because their rates of growth are different so their normals can't be perpendicular to each other everywhere.

So then I thought, hmmm... how about $e^x$ and $e^x-1$? 
Getting all the formulas and plugging in is easy. The simplification part is horrid, and that's what I need help with. Here's what I've done/tried:

$g(x) = e^x,\ g'(x)=e^x$ and $h(x) = e^x-1,\ h'(x)=e^x$.
The point slope of a line is $y-f(a)=f'(a)(x-a)$, where $a$ is the point of 'tangency' to a curve $f(x)$.

So now we have $y-e^a=e^a(x-a)$ and $y-e^b+1=e^b(x-b)$ for some a for $g(x)\  \mathrm{at}\ a$ and $h(x)\ \mathrm{at}\ b$, respectively. We can set these lines equal to each other (by solving for y) to find what a and b are:
$e^a(x-a+1)=e^b(x-b+1)-1$

Now can someone explain how to continue simplifying this to solve for $a$ or $b$?

Comment: You asked about normal lines. So why not take the *normal* line to $y=e^x$ at $x=a$ and see where it intersects $y=e^x-1$. Note that the tangent lines to $y=f(x)$ and $y=f(x)+c$ at $x=a$ are parallel, but the normal lines will not match up *unless* the tangent line is horizontal (which can't happen for your $f(x)$).

Comment: As a somewhat related note, when you set the two lines equal to eachother, you will obtain the point of intersection between the two lines, and the result for $x$ will depend on $a$ and $b$. The two lines will be the same only if the result is independent of $x$, which won't generally be the case here.